SQLite.openDatabase('dbname') is not a function in expo react native
Here's my coding
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite';

const db = SQLite.openDatabase('myDatabase.db');

db.transaction((tx) => {
  tx.executeSql(
    'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, age INTEGER)'
  );
})
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Table created successfully');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error creating table:', error);
  });

I got a error message: SQLite.openDatabase is not a function
I have already install the package
npx expo install expo-sqlite

and import
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite';


Could you post the solution that worked for you? I got the same issue with SDK 51 and expo-sqlite 14.0.4

If you look at the documentation, https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/sqlite/, there is no longer openDatabase only SQLite.openDatabaseSync (and SQLite.openDatabaseAsync). So my guess is changing openDatabase to openDatabaseSync should solve the issue (untested though).

import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite/legacy';

using the legacy driver overcomes this successfully as it continues the "WebSQL-like API"
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/sqlite-legacy/
